# How to programmatically convert a backslash quote to a double backslash quote?

Tags: python

How do you programmatically convert a \" within a Python 3 string variable to \\" for example.

```
str1 = """

"this is a string \"and this is whatever\" and then some"

"""
```

These are my attempts that are not working:

```
str2 = re.sub('\\"', '\\\\', str1)
print('Attempt #1) ' + str2)

and

str3 = str1.replace('\"', '\\"')
print ('Attempt #2) ' + str3)
```

Both of these attempts are not producing what I am trying to do, the output that I am trying to programmatically output is:

"this is a string \\"and this is whatever\\" and then some"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this

```
str1 = r"""

"this is a string \"and this is whatever\" and then some"

"""

print('\\\\'.join(str1.split("\\")))
```

Convert the string into a raw string using 'r', In this way, you prevent escape sequence interpretation.

Comment: Perhaps still more clearly emphasize that without the `r` sigil, the backslashes are removed while Python parses the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code is this:

```
print("this is a string \\\\\" and this is whatever\\\\\" and then some")
```

You need two back-slashes for each `\` and another back-slash to get `"`